# Guardar variável de retorno de serviço no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Tenho um serviço que me retorna um objeto do tipo usuário com o id de um usuario:

Meu objeto:

```
export class Usuario{
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Em meu componente eu instancio meu objeto para que consiga receber o retorno do serviço:

```
usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();
```

E então meu serviço faz a requisição retornando o objeto com o id que preciso:

```
 this.authService.fazerLogin(email,password)
     .subscribe(
          (data) => {
              this.usuario = data;
          )}
```

Se eu faço um console.log(usuario), eu recebo o id que preciso, porém eu gostaria de guardar o retorno em uma variável string no lugar de um objeto para que futuramente eu guarde este valor em um localstorage pra fazer requisições...

Como eu extraio este valor para uma variável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
let suaVariavel = JSON.stringify(data);
```